# How can I find artifacts in Survarium?

Tags: survarium

One of the missions for Scavenger faction is to find an artifact.

Is any equipment required as in S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Clear Sky or are they just visible without any detector as in S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Shadow of Chernobyl? Also, is it possible without protective equipment, such as gas mask?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found some artifacts. They seem to be only located very close to anomalies, and they just sit there waiting to be picked up.

It is possible to pick them up without any additional protection, although I died 3 times before succeeding at picking up spring artifact. And then I died almost instantly after.

In PvP artifacts only seem to last until the end of the round. The are not constantly "on", they have to be activated for short period of time, and they have a cool down time.